# Is there a way to apply the application.html.erb layout to the static folders?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to know if there is a way to make the pages in the rails public folder to be rendered as common pages, that are put on the application.html.erb

I tried using `render '/file.html', layout: true` but it doesn't seem to work.
When I put them to be accessed via link in views, this being `link_to 'test file', '/file.html'` my application css is applied but if I refresh the page it goes away.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know it will help or not but try making controller for that file.
Example:
*Test_Controller*

```
 class TestController < ApplicationController
     def file
          #Read text form the file.. Used in file.html.erb
          @data = File.read("/Desktop/test.txt")
     end
end
```

*file.html.erb*

```
 <h1 align="center"> <b>I am in test file action</b> </h1>
 <p class="pcenter"> <%= @data %></p>
```

where you need that file use,

```
 <%=link_to "File", controller: "Test", action: "file" %>
```

and on *routes.rb*

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
get 'test/file'
```